# Need assistance with creating a Git client-side 'commit-msg' hook

Tags: ruby, git, github, hook, assembla

I have installed the 'ticket_status.rb' server-side hook on Assembla. Although this is exactly what I'm looking for (in theory), it does not flag until the developer attempts to push to the server. If they have made several commits before pushing, it becomes incredibly frustrating to go back through their history and edit any invalid commit messages.

I am looking to create a client-side hook that will reject a developer's commit if an open ticket in Assembla is not referenced in the commit message. I assume that since it is client-side, it will not be able to check if the ticket is open in the Assembla project space. However, if the hook could at least check that '#n' has been included in the commit message (where 0 < n < 10,000), it should catch the majority of invalid commit messages.

GitHub has provided sample code for a client-side 'commit-msg' hook. I would like assistance in modifying the code below to instead search for a ticket number (#n) in the commit message (or an open ticket in the Assembla project space, if possible):

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to check the commit log message.
# Called by "git commit" with one argument, the name of the file
# that has the commit message.  The hook should exit with non-zero
# status after issuing an appropriate message if it wants to stop the
# commit.  The hook is allowed to edit the commit message file.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "commit-msg".

# Uncomment the below to add a Signed-off-by line to the message.
# Doing this in a hook is a bad idea in general, but the prepare-commit-msg
# hook is more suited to it.
#
# SOB=$(git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT | sed -n 's/^\(.*>\).*$/Signed-off-by: \1/p')
# grep -qs "^$SOB" "$1" || echo "$SOB" >> "$1"

# This example catches duplicate Signed-off-by lines.

test "" = "$(grep '^Signed-off-by: ' "$1" |
     sort | uniq -c | sed -e '/^[   ]*1[    ]/d')" || {
    echo >&2 Duplicate Signed-off-by lines.
    exit 1
}
```

I have also provided the source code for the server-side hook that rejects the commit if it does not contain a valid open ticket number in the commit message (ticket_status.rb):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-

#
# Reject a push to a branch if it has commits that do refer a ticket in open state
#

# ref = ARGV[0]
sha_start = ARGV[1]
sha_end = ARGV[2]

# HOOK PARAMS
space = 'space-wiki-name'
api_key = 'user-api-key'
api_secret = 'user-api-secret'
# HOOK START, end of params block

require "net/https"
require "uri"
begin
  require "json"
rescue LoadError
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'json'
end

# Check referred tickets that are in open stage
class TicketValidator
  API_URL = "https://api.assembla.com"

  attr_accessor :space, :api_key, :api_secret

  def initialize()
    @ticket_statuses = []
    @tickets = {}
  end

  def init
    init_http
    load_statuses
  end

  def check(sha, comment)
    comment.to_s.scan(/#\d+/).each do |t|
      ticket = t.tr('#', '')
      # Do not check it twice
      next if @tickets[ticket]
      ticket_js = api_call "/v1/spaces/#{space}/tickets/#{ticket}.json"

      error = nil

      if ticket_js['error'].nil?
        unless @ticket_statuses.include? ticket_js['status'].downcase
          error = "Ticket #{t} is not open!"
        end
      else
        error = ticket_js['error']
      end

      if error
        @tickets[ticket] = {:error => error, :sha => sha}
      else
        @tickets[ticket] = :ok
      end
    end
  end

  def load_statuses
    statuses = api_call "/v1/spaces/#{space}/tickets/statuses.json"
    statuses.each do |status|
      if status["state"] == 1 # open
        @ticket_statuses << status["name"].downcase
      end
    end
  end

  def api_call(uri)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri,
                                 {'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                                  'X-Api-Key' => api_key,
                                  'X-Api-Secret' => api_secret})
    result = @http.request(request)
    JSON.parse(result.body)
  end

  def init_http
    uri = URI.parse(API_URL)
    @http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    @http.use_ssl = true
    @http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  end

  def show_decision!
    @tickets.reject! {|_, value| value == :ok }

    unless @tickets.empty?
      puts "You have references to tickets in closed state"

      @tickets.each do |ticket, details|
        puts "\t#{details[:sha]} - ##{ticket} #{details[:error]}"
      end

      puts "Valid statuses: #{@ticket_statuses.join(', ')}"
      exit 1
    end
  end
end

class Parser
  def initialize(text, validator)
    @text = text
    @validator = validator
  end

  def parse
    commit = nil
    comment = nil

    @validator.init

    @text.to_s.split("\n").each do |line|
      if line =~ /^commit: ([a-z0-9]+)$/i
        new_commit = $1

        if comment
          @validator.check(commit, comment)
          comment = nil
        end

        commit = new_commit
      else
        comment = comment.to_s + line + "\n"
      end
    end

    # Check last commit
    @validator.check(commit, comment) if comment
  end
end

text = `git log --pretty='format:commit: %h%n%B' #{sha_start}..#{sha_end}`

@validator = TicketValidator.new
@validator.space = space
@validator.api_key = api_key
@validator.api_secret = api_secret

Parser.new(text, @validator).parse
@validator.show_decision!
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [commit-msg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commit-msg) validator. It's not ruby but you can easily configure it for your needs and you can even write [your own Assembla reference](https://github.com/clns/node-commit-msg#custom-references) to validate ticket numbers against their API. See the repo README for more details.

Here is a starting point for your custom reference, and its associated test file. I haven't tested it thoroughly but it should be pretty easy to change as you wish, since it's basically JavaScript.

**lib/references/assembla.js**

```js
'use strict';

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var https = require('https');
var util = require('util');

// HOOK PARAMS
var space = 'space-wiki-name';
var apiKey = 'user-api-key';
var apiSecret = 'user-api-secret';

function Ticket(ticket, match) {
    this.allowInSubject = true;
    this.match = match;

    this._ticket = ticket;
}

Ticket.prototype.toString = function() {
    return '#' + this._ticket;
}

Ticket.prototype.isValid = function(cb) {

    var options = {
        hostname: 'api.assembla.com',
        path: util.format('/v1/spaces/%s/tickets/%s.json', space, this._ticket),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type'  : 'application/json',
            'X-Api-Key'     : apiKey,
            'X-Api-Secret'  : apiSecret
        }
    };
    https.get(options, function(res) {
        if (res.statusCode === 404) {
            return cb(null, false); // invalid
        }

        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk.toString();
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            var response = body ? JSON.parse(body) : false;

            if (res.statusCode < 300 && response) {
                return cb(null, true); // valid?
            }

            console.error('warning: Reference check failed with status code %d',
                res.statusCode,
                response && response.message ? ('; reason: ' + response.message) : '');

            cb(null, false); // request errored out?
        });
    });
}

// Fake class that requires the existence of a ticket # in every commit
function TicketRequired() {
    Ticket.call(this);
    this.error = new Error('Commit should include an Assembla ticket #');
}

util.inherits(TicketRequired, Ticket);

TicketRequired.prototype.isValid = function(cb) {
    cb(null, false);
}

Ticket.parse = function(text) {
    var instances = [];
    var cb = function(match, ticket) {
        instances.push( new Ticket(ticket, match) );
    };
    text.replace(/#(-?\d+)\b/gi, cb);
    if (!instances.length) {
        // maybe should skip merge commits here
        instances.push(new TicketRequired());
    }
    return instances;
}

module.exports = Ticket;
```

**test/references/assembla.js**

```js
'use strict';

var assert = require('assert');
var Ticket = require('../../lib/references/assembla');

describe('references/assembla', function() {

    it('should validate correctly using the API', function(done) {
        this.timeout(5000); // allow enough time

        var tickets = Ticket.parse('Change functionality\n\nFixes #13 and #9999 (invalid)');

        var ct = 0;
        var checkDone = function() {
            if (++ct == tickets.length) done();
        };
        var valid = [true, false];

        valid.forEach(function(val, idx) {
            tickets[idx].isValid(function(err, valid) {
                assert.equal(valid, val, tickets[idx].toString());
                checkDone();
            });
        });
    });

    it('should require a ticket #', function() {
        var tickets = Ticket.parse('Commit message without any ticket ref #');

        assert.equal(tickets.length, 1);
        assert.equal(tickets[0].error.message, 'Commit should include an Assembla ticket #');
    });
});
```